# Mongo DB @Field("transaction_id") ignored if @Id annotation applied

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;


@Id
@Field("transaction_id")
private String transactionId;
```

if @Id is applied to a field then transactionId will be saved as transactionId, not as transaction_id (unexpected). Is this a bug or I'm missing something.

```
 spring-data-mongodb-2.1.3.RELEASE
```

Comment: may I know why it should be a bug since you give `_`?

Comment: But it works for any @Field() annotation

Comment: The `@Id`, `@Field` and `@MongoId` annotations have specific purposes - when used with MongoDB applications. You can use them in combination (like @Id and @Field together), but need to have specific purpose.